# code is 32--Windows was able to successfully install device driver software

Tags: drivers

"I am at a lose as to what to do to fix this issue. When I try to update drives, it tells me, I have the best one already. Thing is, no drivers load that the CD/DVD can use, including when I try to hook up an external/USB DVD/CD. Below is what my computer lists as: Problem Details. Unless I find a fix for this, I can not even reinstall a fresh copy of win7 / 64bit that i came with the computer. What to do?"

Description
Windows was able to successfully install device driver software, but the driver software encountered a problem when it tried to run. The problem code is 32.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: PnPDeviceProblemCode
Architecture:   x64
Hardware Id:    SCSI\CdRomATAPI___iHAS124___B_____AL0R
Setup class GUID:   {4d36e965-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
PnP problem code:   00000020
Driver name:    cdrom.sys
Driver version: 6.1.7600.16385
Driver date:    07-13-2009
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1033

Files that help describe the problem
DMI8A8E.tmp.log.xml
LOG8AAF.tmp
cdrom.inf

Comment: Why are you reinstalling the driver? Does the drive not show up? Do you get errors while trying to open CDs/DVDs? Also, Windows drivers shouldn't affect booting from the Win7 DVD in any way to reinstall. Did you try it?

Comment: No drive letter show in device manager, and the DVD/CD drive is unusable because it couldn't be seen. This all happened, when I starting using a new, external USB hard drive from Buffalo, and installed there utility software, which when uninstalled changes nothing. 

I hook up external DVD that worked fine in past. It tries to use the same drives and same message at the desktop unit.The key her is, it keeps saying I have the best now, but, it shows none

win 7 re-installation DVD, How could I? it sees NO drive at all.

Comment: Also, contacting Bullalo, yielded only a reply of, "I cant help, You have done all I would have suggested, already"

Comment: Was hoping Karan would have read my reply, and had some input. But I guess,the real question is: if windows, applies a driver, that is wrong, how do you get it out, and keep it from reloading, saying us it is the best one for that drive?

Comment: Generally you update the driver and install the correct/latest one. Try this: disconnect the USB drive, in Device Manager delete the problem device(s), run [USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) and immediately reboot. (BTW, what sort of PC is this? A laptop with no internal DVD drive?)

Comment: ibuypower NZXT gaming computer, about a year old. AMD Athlon 2 X2 245 processor, 8 gb ram, NVIDIA GeGorce GT 520 with 1GB of dedicated  win7 prem 64-bit SP1.

Comment: ibuypower NZXT gaming computer, about a year old. AMD Athlon 2 X2 245 processor, 8 gb ram, NVIDIA GeGorce GT 520 with 1GB of dedicated  win7 prem 64-bit SP1.  The usb drive was never connected, except when i needed a 2nd drive to copy CD or DVD's

Comment: Did you give up on me, and my issue Karan? How do you get, an non appropriate, non working driver out of a win 7 plug and play, that just wont leave? Thanks

Comment: Did you try what I suggested above? You never said if you did... I would also recommend you try the USB DVD drive on another PC, just to confirm that it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: yes / no, I had already done that before we started writing. It just used the same, non useable driver when i did. The usb DVD works on all others fine.